# Scatter/gather async socket I/O in .NET

Tags: .net, asynchronous, stream

I'm trying to use the Stream.BeginWrite Async I/O API in .NET for a high-throughput situation with many short messages. As such, a scatter/gather API will reduce the number of context switches (and CPU usage) tremendously. Does this API use the LPBUFFERS Win32 API at all? Is there an alternative API for Scatter/Gather I/O?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no way to do socket scatter/gather I/O in .NET. According to a MSFT blog post, there may be a similar API in .NET 4.5 (whatever that is...)

Comment: Do you have a link to that blog post?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the .net sources, the accepted answer seems to be wrong.

`SocketAsyncEventArgs` has a [`BufferList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs.bufferlist%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) attribute. When that is used, instead of the `Buffer` attribute that can only hold a single contiguous block of memory, operations can make use of scatter/gather DMA, as [`Socket.SendAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,102e8374338a49cb) uses [`WSASend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742203(v=vs.85).aspx) internally, that

> allows multiple send buffers to be specified making it applicable to the scatter/gather type of I/O

and [`Socket.SendAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs)`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Sockets/Socket.cs,194ae41217fbaf74) uses [`WSARecv`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741688%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that

> allows multiple receive buffers to be specified making it applicable to the scatter/gather type of I/O

I don't have the .net 3.5 sources handy, but `BufferList` exists since .net 3.5, so scatter/gather might have been supported since .net 3.5. The minimum OS requirements for WSASend and WSARecv exist are documented as Windows Vista / Server 2003.

N.B. I don't know what stream you are using, but `NetworkStream.BeginWrite` sends a single buffer to the WSASend, so you cannot use that for scatter/gathering.

Answer (score 1):

I would be surprised if you could get to the scatter/gather api's from the BCL (it's for the l33t w1n32 haxx0rz, you know?), but there's always P/Invoke (which is suprisingly easy to use, I've found).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dig into the guts of the framework, there are a few ways to do it:

1) Reflector

2) MS recently opened up the source for debugging purposes, you can step into it with VS2008 if you enable the option under Debugging/Options/General

3) Koders.com seem to be hosting the framework source too:

http://www.koders.com/csharp/fidCE09E83BE706D0BD370658C3785E82D3A13FC2CE.aspx?s=flush()#L109